# change value of several variables in one line javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Is there a way to change the value of several variables in one line? The code below is working, but very repetitive. How can I change the values of i, j, k in a more elegant way? Also is it possible to write an if function for all three variables instead of repeating it three times.

```
var i = 0;
var j = -1;
var k = -2;

function fn() {
   // magic happening;

    i += 1;
    j += 1;
    k += 1;

    if (i > 3) {
        i = 0;
    }
    if (j > 3) {
        j = 0;
    }
    if (k > 3) {
        k = 0;
    }

    // more stuff happening
}
```

Comment: Use a comma? `i += 1, j += 1, k += 1;` - Also, you could use the ternary operator to make it shorter `i = (i > 3) 0 : ++i`.

Comment: using commas `i +=1, j +=1, ... ;`

Comment: try this `var i = 0, j = -1, k = -2;` and `i += 1, j+=1, k+=1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;
var j = -1;
var k = -2;

function fn() {
    i = (i <= 2) ? ++i : 0;
    j = (j <= 2) ? ++j : 0;
    k = (k <= 2) ? ++k : 0;
}
```

Or by writing another function:

```
var i = 0;
var j = -1;
var k = -2;

function fn() {
    i = calculateIt(i);
    j = calculateIt(j);
    k = calculateIt(k);
}

function calculateIt(value) {
    return (value <= 2) ? ++value : 0;
}
```

Comment: [(i+1)>3] should become [i > 2]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single expression for one assignment.

```
i = i > 2 ? 0 : i + 1;
```

You can make an function which keeps the interval.

```
function incAndLimit(v) {
    return v > 2 ? 0 : v + 1;
}

// usage
i = incAndLimit(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign value like this:

```
i++,j++,k++;
```

Comment: This ignores the event where `i,j,k` are higher than 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put the variables in an array you can use ES2015's `.map` and lambdas:

```
var list = [0, -1, -2] // replaces separate i, j, and k
list = list.map(x => x++)
           .map(x => x > 3 ? 0 : x);
```

You can combine these two functions

```
list = list.map(x => {
    x++;
    return x > 3 ? 0 : x
});
```

Even if you can't put these variables in an array I'd suggest putting the checking function in a separate function:

```
function abv3(x) {
    x++;
    return x > 3 ? 0 : x;
}

i = abv3(i), j = abv3(j), k = abv3(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var [i, j, k] = [0, -1, -2]
                .map(v => v + 1)
                .map(v => v > 3 ? 0 : v);
```

Note that this code requires ES6 compatible environment.

Comment: This only works for declaring the variables, it doesn't work for changing their values once they've been created.

Comment: You can always redeclare them with `var`. But yea, there might be a cleaner way depending on what you want to do inside the code. The functional way would be to chain all actions together so you need to make only one declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is it by double ES6 array destructuring

```js
var  i = 0,
     j = -1,
     k = -2,
update = ([x,y,z]) => [++x>3?0:x, ++y>3?0:y, ++z>3?0:z];

[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
[i,j,k] = update([i,j,k]);
console.log(i,j,k);
```